# Redux runSaga (Unit testing) error throws undefined on local variable. How do I mock a local variable using Jest or Sinon?

Tags: jestjs, sinon, redux-saga

Running runSaga on my redux saga generator function my window variable is thrown as undefined but my test files are passing is there any way to mock the window variable?

Below is my redux saga generator function

```js
import api from 'my-api';
    
const getSuburb = () => window.userCookies.selectedSuburb;

function* saga(payload) {
 const action = yield take('REQUEST_LIBRARY');
 const selectedSuburb = yield call(getSuburb);
 const getStateLibraries = yield call(api.getLibraries, selectedSuburb, action.userId);
 yield put(loadLibrary(getStateLibraries)
}
```

On running the above code I receive list of libraries with respect to the suburb, I have another state holds the suburb information where I can use select to retrieve it. The code works fine

Unit test cases to test redux saga using RunSaga

```js
const recordSaga = async function (sagaHandler, initalAction) {
  const dispatchedActions = [];
  const fakeStore = {
    getState: () => (initialState),
    dispatch: action => dispatchedActions.push(action),
  };
  await runSaga(
    fakeStore,
    sagaHandler,
    initalAction,
  ).done;
  return dispatchedActions;
};

describe('Run Saga', () => {
 it('should dispatch action libraries', async() => {
  const dispatched = await recordSaga(saga, { user_id:2 });
  expect(dispatched).toContainEqual(loadLibrarySuccess(someProfile));
 }
```

While running the above I am getting on `selectedSuburb` as undefined because window.userCookies.totalSuburbs is not defined, is there any better way to mock the `getSuburb` function?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to look at how Redux-Saga docs suggest [sagas testing](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Testing.html). In unit test only logic of function `saga` should be tested and not calls to any third party function. And `yield` keyword greatly helps with this.

Essentially we test that generator function (function `saga` in this example) will return correct objects on each call. So unit test for `saga` function will look like (not tested, just sample)

```
describe('Run Saga', () => {
  it('should dispatch action libraries', () => {
    const gen = saga()  // As saga is generator function it will return generator object
    expect(gen.next().value).toStrictEqual(take('REQUEST_LIBRARY'))
    expect(gen.next({ userId: 'user1' } /* here can be action returned by take('REQUEST_LIBRARY') in saga */).value).toStrictEqual(call(getSuburb))
    expect(gen.next({ suburb: 'central suburb' } /* here can be selectedSuburb returned by call(getSuburb) in saga */).value).toStrictEqual(call(api.getLibraries, { suburb: 'central suburb' }, 'user1'))
    // The values of selectedSuburb and action.userId are from calls to gen.next()
    expect(gen.next({ libraries: ['lib 1', 'lib 2'] } }).value).toStrictEqual(put(loadLibrary({ libraries: ['lib 1', 'lib 2'] }))
    expect(gen.next().done).toBe(true); // Saga is finished
  }
})
```

So unit test only checks saga itself and don't call any functions that saga calls when executed. So you don't need to mock anything at all when using sagas. This confirm to idea of unit testing to test only single unit of code (function) in isolation.

As you may noticed, value returned from `yield` should be passed to `next()` function but on *next* line. This is how generator works.

Comment: I would slightly deviate from that theory, there is a good article https://dev.to/phil/the-best-way-to-test-redux-sagas-4hib to prove why step by step testing is rubbish. The ultimate question is "How you mock a local variable using sinon or jest"

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I have modified the code as follows to make sure my test cases are running, but I would still looking for the perfect solution to mock the local variable

```js
function* saga(payload) {
 const action = yield take('REQUEST_LIBRARY');
 const selectedSuburb = window.userCookies.selectedSuburb
 const getStateLibraries = yield call(api.getLibraries, selectedSuburb, action.userId);
 yield put(loadLibrary(getStateLibraries)
}
```

and my test case looks like

```js
const recordSaga = async function (sagaHandler, initalAction) {
  const dispatchedActions = [];
  const fakeStore = {
    getState: () => (initialState),
    dispatch: action => dispatchedActions.push(action),
  };
  await runSaga(
    fakeStore,
    sagaHandler,
    initalAction,
  ).done;
  return dispatchedActions;
};

describe('Run Saga', () => {
 it('should dispatch action libraries', async() => {
 const callback = sinon.stub(this, 'userCookies.selectedSuburb');
   callback.onCall(0).returns('suburb_name');
  const dispatched = await recordSaga(saga, { user_id:2 });
  expect(dispatched).toContainEqual(loadLibrarySuccess(someProfile));
 }
```